# Limit access to classes from rule [drools]

Tags: drools

I'm using drools with decision tables.
The decision table contains java code.

But for security reasons, I do not want that the designer of the excel be able to call any code from rule.
I want him to be limited on objects of model that we have created. I do not want to let him access file system or whatever.

Is it possible to configure drools to limit access in the DRL to only specific classes?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible.

The author of the rules (DRL or otherwise) can import any class that's available to them via the classpath.

Comment: Hello thank you.
But can't we play with classloaders ? I see that new KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl(ClassLoader cl) and KieServices.getKieClasspathContainer(ClassLoader cl); can get a classloader in parameters.
But I can't make them work as expected.